# How To turn Laptop screen off until specific key pressed?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I want to turn the laptop screen off even if the mouse moved or key clicked
I have a lenovo laptop y50 that can do that Fn+F2
i want that on my other laptops

Comment: That key combination turns the backlight on/off. You will need to look at the user manual for your other laptops to see whether they have similar functionality. Not all laptops will do this.

Comment: May I know whether the issue is you need block screen of the laptop? Does Windows key + L can help you?